# UIView gets added flipped

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have created an empty *.xib, added classes and referenced them.

I need to show the control over all UIViews currently displayed. I do this to show the control:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ExternalDisplayRemoteControl *remoteControl = [[ExternalDisplayRemoteControl alloc]initWithNibName:@"ExternalDisplayRemoteControl" bundle:nil];
remoteControl.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, appDelegate.window.bounds.size.width-40, appDelegate.window.bounds.size.height-40);
remoteControl.view.alpha = 0.0;

[appDelegate.window addSubview:remoteControl.view];



//Display the customView with animation

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
   [remoteControl.view setAlpha:1.0];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

In the Interface Builder i have tried to set orientation to landscape - doesn't help

And the result is:

**The UIView that i add is getting rotated 90 degrees clockwise... Why?**

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

This solution: doesn't respect device rotations.

Better solution:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window)
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:remoteControl.view];
```